# How to calculate means grouping by indice in Tensorflow?

Tags: python, numpy, tensorflow, aggregate, k-means

To implement k-means algorithm I have calculated cluster indices `0..K-1` of shape `(N, 1)` for each sample:

```
0
1
2
2
1
1
...
0
```

Now I want to take samples tensor of shape `(N, 3)` and compute new means of shape `(K, 3)`.

In `numpy` I would write:

```
for i_cluster in range(n_clusters):
   mu[i_cluster, :] = X[cluster_indice == i_cluster, :].mean(0)
```

How to do the same with `Tensorflow`?

**UPDATE**

I probably need to use [`tf.dynamic_partition()`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/dynamic_partition)...

Comment: This really is a [Can someone help me?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/284236/why-is-can-someone-help-me-not-an-actual-question) kind of question so far ..

Answer (score 0):

I wrote this way:

```
def graph_clusters_new_mu(self, x, cluster_indice, ordinals):

    new_mus = []
    for i_cluster in range(self.n_clusters):
        is_i_cluster = tf.squeeze(tf.equal(cluster_indice, i_cluster))
        x_cluster = tf.boolean_mask(x, is_i_cluster)
        x_cluster_mean = tf.reduce_mean(x_cluster, axis=0 )
        new_mus.append( x_cluster_mean )

    new_mu = tf.stack(new_mus)

    return new_mu
```